# Python TensorFlow - what is tf.flags.FLAGS?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pycharm

What is the purpose of parsing flags in TensorFlow? What is tf.flags.FLAGS?
& what does this code statement do?

```
FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS
FLAGS._parse_flags()
print("\nParameters:")
for attr, value in sorted(FLAGS.__flags.items()):
    print("{}={}".format(attr.upper(), value))
print("")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Tensorflow the flags are basically run parameters for your model. Later in the code you will probably see a tf.app.run() which will utilize these flags. What this code does is grab all the currently existing flags, and print them all out in this format:

```
Parameters:
learning_rate=0.01
max_steps=2000
hidden1=128
hidden2=32
batch_size=100
```

These parameters are just examples that I found online, and will vary from model to model. Hope this helps.